# How to ignore environment directory when using python ruff linter in console

Tags: python, linter, ruff

I was trying ruff linter. I have a file structure like below

```
project_folder
├── env # Python enviroment [python -m venv env]
│   ├── Include
│   ├── Lib
│   ├── Scripts
│   ├── ...
├── __init__.py
└── numbers.py
```

I am trying to use this [code](https://beta.ruff.rs/docs/tutorial/)

I activated the environment inside the project_folder and ran the script below

```bash
ruff check .
```

but ruff also checked the env file.
[Image.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaofn.png)

how to ignore env file like below linux script

```bash
tree -I env
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `exclude` option,

```
ruff check --exclude=env .
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add it to your ruff configuration in your project root:

```ini
#.ruff.toml

exclude= ["env"]
```

See: https://docs.astral.sh/ruff/configuration/